# Unable to shutdown - libvirt-guest.sh

Tags: shutdown, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

after doing an upgrade (via update && apt upgrade) Ubuntu doesn't turn off or reboot.
Every time I try to turn it off or restart it, appears this string and i'm forced to switch off with the power key.

```
libvirt-guest.sh: Running guest on default URI: no running guests
```

After doing some research on the net I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: Nobody can help me?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. I contacted Red Hat libvirt support at libvirt.org and they actualy do not know the root cause of this problem, however they suggested to disable the service at boot: sudo systemctl disable libvirt-guests.sh, which works fine, however this is just a workaroud, not a solution. On 15.04 that didn't happen to me. I've figured out that libvirt got installed on my PC after installing gnome-boxes as it depends on libvirt and qemu. I am still investigating the root cause.

Comment: What libvirt version do you have? Have you tried newer versions?

Answer (score 0):

When I see this message, indicating that there are no running guests, my machine actually does shut down.  I found this thread because the opposite is happening: if I still have a VM running, then my host won't shutdown as somehow libvirt cannot shutdown the running VM('s).

```
libvirt-guests.sh: Waiting for guest xxx to shut down, 300 seconds left
```

This never succeeds and I'm forced to hard poweroff my laptop as well..

I've seen some hints and launchpad bug reports about the format of the guests list having unexpected newlines in it's output, causing the shutdown call to fail.

I'm not sure how this can help you, I just wanted to share this..

Kind regards,

Comment: The script responsponsible for this is located at /usr/lib/libvirt/libvirt-guests.sh. If you read it you will see that the shutdown timeout is set to 300 - SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT=300. You can change it to 1 if you want.

Comment: Hi @jedi, I'm not sure if I want the timeout to be reduced to 1 second, I'd rather have libvirt succeed in shutting down the running VM's instead.

Answer (score 0):

This sometimes happens to me too, actually the UI (mine is kde desktop) is launched at tty2, so by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> (changing the current tty) the system will shutdown.

I don't know why, but this is the only soft workaround I have found till now. hope it helps.